# How to close a YUI autocomplete box by clicking an external link

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete box which I would like to be able to close when the user clicks a link. I think I would just have to somehow "get" the autocomplete, then use the .collapseContainer method.

I don't know how to "get" a YUI object, though, or if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matt Parker at the [YUI Library forums](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7300) for this one:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on("myLinkElement","click", function(ev){
  myAutoComplete.collapseContainer();
  // whatever else...
});
```